# Tensor Flow load saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I got the tensorflow lite model from google teachable machine and I want do a post training quantization.
I saved the tflite model in my drive and use the following code in google colab

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("D:\\FYP\\tflite floating point model converted_tflite\\converted_tflite")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

the error show that

**OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)**

.

.

.

saved_model_proto, debug_info = (
--> 949       **loader_impl.parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir))**

.

.

.

**OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: D:\FYP\tflite floating point model converted_tflite\converted_tflite/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}**

The savedmodel.tflite and the label.txt is in the directory

There are tensorflow hub error that have solution in the forum but I don't think it is applicable in my case.

Is the loading saved model only applicable in tensorflow but not in tensorflow lite ?

I don't have another file like.h5 .pb , is it still workable ?

Here is the original error code:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ed888086d160> in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("D:\\FYP\\tflite floating point model converted_tflite\\converted_tflite")
      3 converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
      4 converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
      5 converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py in from_saved_model(cls, saved_model_dir, signature_keys, tags)
   1646 
   1647     with context.eager_mode():
-> 1648       saved_model = _load(saved_model_dir, tags)
   1649     if not signature_keys:
   1650       signature_keys = saved_model.signatures

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in load(export_dir, tags, options)
    934     ValueError: If `tags` don't match a MetaGraph in the SavedModel.
    935   """
--> 936   result = load_internal(export_dir, tags, options)["root"]
    937   return result
    938 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in load_internal(export_dir, tags, options, loader_cls, filters)
    947     tags = nest.flatten(tags)
    948   saved_model_proto, debug_info = (
--> 949       loader_impl.parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir))
    950 
    951   if (len(saved_model_proto.meta_graphs) == 1 and

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py in parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir)
     55     parsed. Missing graph debug info file is fine.
     56   """
---> 57   saved_model = parse_saved_model(export_dir)
     58 
     59   debug_info_path = file_io.join(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py in parse_saved_model(export_dir)
    114   else:
    115     raise IOError(
--> 116         f"SavedModel file does not exist at: {export_dir}{os.path.sep}"
    117         f"{{{constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PBTXT}|"
    118         f"{constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB}}}")

OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: D:\FYP\tflite floating point model converted_tflite\converted_tflite/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

Answer (score 0):

SavedModel is a format which mainly consists of

- saved_model.pb which has the graph structure
- assets directory which contains files used by your model
- variables directory which is values of variables in your model in a checkpoint format.

see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) for more details.

TFLite file, is a flatbuffer which represents your model after it got compiled/converted using TfLiteConverter to be used by TFLite runtime interpreter.
It doesn't have or use the saved model format explained above.

So you can't use from_saved_model to try to do this.

My suggestion is to get the original saved model and try to convert it with post training quantization enabled.